# How to calculate MSE criteria in RandomForestRegression?

Tags: python, random-forest, mse

I'm now using RandomForestRegressor from sklearn.ensemble to analyze a dataset and I select "mse" as the function to measure the quality of a split. But I'm not quite clear how the mse is calculated. Could anyone explain it to me here (better with equations) or provide me some references on that? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

> Mean Squared Error (MSE) is calculated by squaring all of the errors (to make them positive) and then taking the mean value of those squares. It is a single value; "for each tree, we get a difference between two MSE values. Averaging over trees gives the mean difference between the two MSE values". [ref](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/510917/240550)

> ... However, the Random Forest calculates the MSE using the predictions obtained from evaluating the same data. Train in every tree but only considering the data is not taken from bootstrapping to construct the tree, wether the data that it is in the *OOB (OUT-OF-BAG)*. Then it averages the predictions for all the OOB predictions for each sample of data. ... [ref](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/455854/240550)

*MSE*, metric is one of the cost function methods. Consider that your model green line is in the following picture, and those blue points are data (observations). MSE, as its name suggests, is the mean summation of square areas of all data points with respect to a line, which all in all represents your **model errors**.

[image: img]

MSE can be calculated by:

[image: img]

> It shows **how good or bad the model is**. The **smaller** MSE, the **better** model!

More info:

[Understanding Regression Error Metrics in Python](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/understanding-regression-error-metrics/)

[Introduction to Loss Functions](https://blog.algorithmia.com/introduction-to-loss-functions/)

**Update 30.05.2019:** To verify things, you can dig into the documentation and sometimes in codes as well, based on its documentation [RandomForestRegressor()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) , MSE is nothing else than **variance reduction** as feature selection criterion even when you check the source code it is used for **measuring the quality of a split**. On the other hand, if you are doubtful instead of the MSE approach in `RandomForestRegressor()`, you can use it independently by customizing `criterion` like this:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
#Feature Selection
criterion = mean_squared_error(y, predictions)
RandomForestRegressor( ...,criterion= criterion,...)
```

or using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```py
import numpy as np
criterion = np.mean((y_test - est.predict(X_test))**2)
```

More [info](https://towardsdatascience.com/random-forest-regression-5f605132d19d)

Comment: what is the difference between the confusion matrix? i can confide in a confusion matrix from sklearn?

Comment: @Mario, thank you for your quick answer. Your answer is a general explanation of what MSE is. But I think MSE calculation in RF regression is different. MSE here is a split criterion; based on my understanding, this means we have to calculate many MSEs due to various potential split points, and find the split point which results in a minimum MSE. But again, I don't really know how it is calculated in RF Regression model.

Comment: @Mario Let's make up an example to show my question clearer.  We have a dataset with two features A and B and one target C. At one node (assume we have m numbers of feature A here), we randomly pick feature A for split. What does RF do? It will try each value of A from the m numbers and find the best value of A for split which gives smallest MSE after this split.  I think MSE of one split is the sum of MSEs in the two sub-nodes. You need a comparison of m MSE values, i.e., MSE is calculated per potential split point, not at the end of the tree. Is that correct?

Comment: @ZhendongCao Based on documentation in `sklearn`, RandomForrest Regressor `criterion` is: **The function to measure the quality of a split**
It's a performance measure (by default, MSE) which helps the algorithm to decide on a rule for an optimum split on a node in a tree. You can check it out this [paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume13/biau12a/biau12a.pdf) and its computation for better understanding. I assume that it checks every split point and take average over all of'em.