# How to find RMSE without test value in python

Tags: pandas, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

First, I am wondering if is there a way to find the RMSE value with the y-test value(I can do it if I have a y-test value). For instance, we have train data and test data. But in the test data, we don't have the y value. So after fitting a model how do you calculate RMSE? I know to do that I need pred_y(which I got using the trained model) and test_y(which I don't have)

```
mse = sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error(test_y, pred_y)
print("RMSE: %s" % math.sqrt(mse))
```

Is it possible to find RMSE without test_y? If yes, how?

Comment: No, RMSE is defined in terms of the difference between predicted and actual. If you have no actual values, you can't calculate it.

Comment: If we keep it simple and, instead of RMSE, consider MSE or MAE, then imagine geometrically without having actual\true value as the label ( `y` ), it's impossible to estimate the *distance* for MAE or [*area* for MSE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56369702/10452700). Thus without knowing `test_y` within the test-set, we can't solve this, and it will be nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

To calculate any kind of error terms (like RMSE), you need the true values. If you don't have them, there is nothing you can do. That's unless you actually have a way to find or determine the true values.